# How to pass the output of command2 as a input of command1 in a Windows command prompt

Tags: visual-c++, unix, sua

In my program I have to use the `diff` command from SUA to find out the difference of 2 files.

I use the a command as follows,

```
diff xx yy
```

here

```
xx - /a/s/xx.txt

yy - /a/s/yy/txt
```

The path of `xx.txt` and `yy.txt` is in Windows format. But in SUA 'diff' command accepts the path in UNIX format as `/dev/fs/C/a/s/xx.txt` and `/dev/fs/C/a/s/yy.txt`.

We have a command `winpath2unix` that will convert the path into Unix format. So I want to use the `diff` command as follows in my program,

```
diff 'winpath2unix xx' 'winpath2unix yy'
```

Here I want to run `winpath2unix` command first and need to pass the output of these commands to `diff` command.

In C shell it is working fine. But in the command prompt its not working.

Is there any option to run this command?

Or how can i use `csh` in CreateProcess?

Comment: How are you currently calling `diff` from your program?  I have an idea or two, but I'd like to see what you're currently doing

Comment: Hi @San, were you able to try either of the answers to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your question on some other forum. :)

Use `-c` to send a command as argument to tcsh, "" is used to quote double quotes, if the path winpath prints a path including space.

```
LPTSTR cmd[] = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\Windows\\posix.exe /u /c /bin/tcsh -c \"/bin/diff \"\"`winpath2unix /x/xx.txt`\"\" \"\"`winpath2unix /x/yy.txt`\"\"\""));

int RetVal = CreateProcess(NULL,
                           cmd,
                           NULL,
                           NULL,
                           TRUE,
                           NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                           NULL,
                           NULL,
                           &sInfo,
                           &pInfo);
DWORD error = GetLastError();
```

More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If by the command prompt, you mean `cmd.exe`, there is a trick that can help you which uses the `FOR` command to set a variable in a batch file.  So you would create a batch file that looked something like this

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%A in ('winpath2unix %1') do SET xxWinPath=%%A
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%A in ('winpath2unix %2') do SET yyWinPath=%%A
diff xxWinPath yyWinPath
```

If we called this batch file `doDiff.bat`, you would call it with the syntax `doDiff.bat xx yy`.

Another description of this technique is [here](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/save-output-of-dos-command-to-variable.html).  Raymond Chen also demonstrates a similar technique [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/05/11/2532913.aspx).  The official documentation lives on [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true) under the header **Iterating and file parsing**.